# 2014 Skoda Octavia - Unidentified part

Tags: part-identification, skoda, octavia

I recently bought a 2014 SKODA Octavia 1.4 TSI Elegance DSG 5dr and found the below random piece of plastic in the glove box. I appreciate any help in identifying it. I ideally want to know what is is used for and if it is needed! I tried Googling the numbers but it didn't show anything that made sense to me.

Appears to have the following written on it

```
>POM<   1
8 103 713
S ...
Czech Republic
```

[image: Unidentified 1]
[image: Unidentified 2]
[image: Unidentified 3]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Only  thing I can tell you for sure is [POM or Polyoxymethylene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyoxymethylene) is the material it's made out of.  Beyond that, we can probably assume the 8103713 is the part number, but a cursory search didn't turn up anything.

Comment: Is it a blanking plate that was removed when some optional accessory was fitted? It looks like the long rectangle has a clip at each end which would fit into a hole in the interior trim, and cover it.

Comment: It could also be a random piece of plastic that someone couldn't identify so they put it in the glove in case they figured out what it was later.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 8103713 doesn't fit the format for a VAG part number, feck knows what it means though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a piece that is of same shape (not dismounted) in my new Octavia III 5E(facelift). It's in the glove box, fitted to the left, down. We have been guessing what it could be used for and it looks like pen and paper holder. The panel is pressing to the left side wall of the glove box, so you could fit thin things behind it. I would say it just got loose, though I have no clue how it is fixated.

Comment: That makes perfect sense; it's obvious when you know! Thanks for solving the mystery